# Загрузка изображений на сервер.

Tags: php, изображения

Закачиваю изображения на сервер. Перед отправкой делаю проверку на тип изображения.

Недавно заметил, что некоторые изображения не закачиваются.

```
 $filenametmp[$count] = $_FILES["img".$i]["tmp_name"];

 $imageinfo = getimagesize($filenametmp[$count]);
 if($imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/gif' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpg' &&         $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/png' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpeg'&& $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/JPG' ) {
echo "Данный тип файла фотографий не поддерживается. Вернитесь назад и выберите фотографию с другим разрешением .jpeg, .gif или .png \n";
exit;
}
```

Изображение SDC10491.JPG

Comment: s/разрешением/расширением/

Comment: ну выведите $imageinfo['mime'] когда не успешно
а условие лучше так сделать:

if(!in_array($imageinfo['mime'],array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/png')

Comment: Пустота. НИчего не выводит  $imageinfo['mime'].

Comment: проверяйте массив файлов `var_dump($_FILES);`, а так же посмотрите сколько ваш сервак макс. размер файла позволяет загрузить.